# Animate UIButton back to its original position swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, ios-animations

I have wriiten following code to animate my button

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

        assistButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.maxX - 75, y: self.view.frame.maxY - 120, width: width, height: height)

    })
```

This code works fine but after some user action I want to animate this button back to original position for that written following code

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

    assistButton.frame = CGRect(x: lastX, y: lastY, width: width, height: height)

})
```

**But Above code is not working**

lastX and LastY value are initialised in **viewDidLoad** as below

```
    lastX = assistButton.frame.minY
    lastY = assistButton.frame.minX
```

Comment: try viewDidAppear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38056763/4311935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting 'lastX' and 'lastY' in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.